# Virtual PC "The page cannot be displayed" error connecting to iis7.5 site on Win7 host

Tags: iis-7.5, virtualization

I setup virtual pc with the Windows XP IE6 VHD to test a site on Windows 7 host.
I created a loopback adapter connection on the host. I have several sites on IIS 7.5, I'm able to connect to all of them except one. And it's the site I need to test...
I get "The page cannot be displayed" error. The site loads fine from the host(Windows 7).
I've made sure the permissions match that of the other sites that do load. I've recreated the application in IIS manager.
Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: What's different about the site? Anything obviously different in the site Bindings configuration between a working and non-working one?

Comment: Hi. No, all the sites are under Default Web Site and accessed by ip/site1, ip/site2 etc. and have the same bindings "http:*:80:,net.tcp:808:*,net.pipe:*,net.msmq:localhost,msmq.formatname:localhost". I just tested by putting in a html file in my sites directory, the html file loads fine. So I thought it might be some error happening in iis/asp.net and its not been shown to the virtual pc, so I enabled detailed error but no error is shown in IE6 virtual pc.

Comment: Gotcha - in IIS parlance, they're not "sites", they're applications or virtual directories. All are part of the same site, and share the same bindings. This means there's something interesting going on with the app/vdir in question. Check \inetpub\logs\w3svc for clues - is the IE instance even requesting the page? There should be no difference in its ability to connect to either, except for server-side differences, as the same TCP socket could be used for either.

Comment: And! Turn off Show Friendly HTTP Errors in IE's Internet Options -> Advanced, just in case it's IE being helpful.